# make_bucket failed: s3://bucket_test/ 'module' object has no attribute 'sslwrap' python 2.7.6

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3

I tried to create amazon instance but I encountered this error make_bu. cket failed: s3://bucket_test/ 'module' object has no attribute 'sslwrap' and I am using python 2.7.6. I had the same error using even when I switched to python 2.7.9. I really don't know how to handle this error.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information than that.

Comment: I think it is essantially du to ssl.py file:

`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 238, in __init__
    self._sslobj = _ssl.sslwrap(self._sock, server_side,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sslwrap'`